# Display additional content panel based on boolean block in Wagtail Editor Interface

Tags: django, django-models, wagtail

I want to add a boolean block to my Wagtail model and show a content panel field only if it is checked. I have figured out how to add a boolean block and render content in the template based on its value, but not how to do control the editor interface with it. Here is my model. I want to show the heldover_from, date chooser block, only when heldover boolean is checked.

```
class AgendaPage(Page):
author= models.CharField(max_length=255)
date = models.DateField('Post date')
agenda = StreamField([
    ('agenda_item', blocks.StreamBlock([
        ('item_title', blocks.TextBlock()),
        ('item_text', blocks.TextBlock()),
        ('mtg_doc', blocks.StructBlock([
            ('doc_description', blocks.TextBlock()),
            ('doc_link', blocks.TextBlock()),
            ('submitted_late', blocks.BooleanBlock(required=False, help_text='Submitted Late')),
            ('heldover', blocks.BooleanBlock(required=False, help_text='Held Over')),
            ('heldover_from', blocks.DateBlock(required=False, help_text="Held Over From")

        ]))
      ]
    ))
])




content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
    FieldPanel('author'),
    FieldPanel('date'),
    StreamFieldPanel('agenda'),

]
```

(And after I figure this out, I want to know if I can make it required, but only if heldover is checked, not for the whole streamblock)

```
{% for block in self.agenda %}
  {% if block.block_type == "agenda_item" %} {# will always be true, but included here for clarity #}
  <li>
    {% for subblock in block.value %}
        {% if subblock.block_type == "item_title" %}
            <h2>{{subblock.value}}</h2>
         {% elif subblock.block_type == "item_text" %}
                 <p>{{subblock.value}}</p>
         {% elif subblock.block_type == "mtg_doc" %}
                <p><a href="{{subblock.value.doc_link}}">{{subblock.value.doc_description}}</a><br />
            {% ifequal subblock.value.submitted_late True %}
             (Submitted Late)
            {% endifequal %}
                </p>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</li>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Can you show your current template code, please?

Comment: I have posted the current template code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by overriding the form template for the StructBlock as described in http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.6.2/topics/streamfield.html#custom-editing-interfaces-for-structblock - although it does require fiddling with some fairly low-level details of the form markup.

First, let's pull out the `mtg_doc` block definition into its own class for a bit more breathing room:

```
class MtgDocBlock(blocks.StructBlock):
    doc_description = blocks.TextBlock()
    doc_link = blocks.TextBlock()
    submitted_late = blocks.BooleanBlock(required=False, help_text='Submitted Late')
    heldover = blocks.BooleanBlock(required=False, help_text='Held Over')
    heldover_from = blocks.DateBlock(required=False, help_text="Held Over From")

    class Meta:
        form_template = 'myapp/block_forms/mtg_doc.html'


class AgendaPage(Page):
    ...
    agenda = StreamField([
        ('agenda_item', blocks.StreamBlock([
            ('item_title', blocks.TextBlock()),
            ('item_text', blocks.TextBlock()),
            ('mtg_doc', MtgDocBlock())
        ])
    ])
```

Here I've added a `form_template` parameter to the block class, which specifies an alternative template to use to render the form in place of Wagtail's built in one. Since we don't want to change the actual rendering, we can just include the built-in template (located at `wagtailadmin/block_forms/struct.html`) and add a bit of JS behaviour to it. In `templates/myapp/block_forms/mtg_doc.html`:

```
{% include "wagtailadmin/block_forms/struct.html" %}

<script>
    // all fields of the block have a common prefix on the ID,
    // which is available as the template variable 'prefix'.
    // Retrieve the 'heldover' checkbox
    var checkbox = $('#{{ prefix }}-heldover');

    // Retrieve the 'li' element containing the 'heldover_from' field
    var field = $('#{{ prefix }}-alignment').closest('li');

    function showHideField() {
        // update the visibility of field according to the state of
        // the checkbox
        if (checkbox.is(':checked')) {
            field.show();
        } else {
            field.hide();
        }
    }
    // call showHideField immediately to reflect the initial state
    // of the checkbox
    showHideField();
    // trigger showHideField whenever the checkbox state is changed
    checkbox.change(showHideField);
</script>
```

Comment: Gasman-Thanks, I knew I wanted to add javascript to make this happen but I was not sure where/how. I have a noob question: I do not see the wagtailadmin directory in my site folder structure, any idea why that might be

Comment: This is because they are at the wagtail core level not at the app/project level

Comment: Is this still the preferred way to do this (wagtail 2.1)? Thanks for a great framework gasman!